# Jungle camps in Conquest

Tags: smite

What are the timers and health points for each of the camps in conquest and joust? And how do fire giant and gold fury scale?

Answer (score 1):

As of Season 6 the jungle camps for conquest have their base Health pool decreased but their increased health per level increased and it goes as follows:

**Conquest:**

- Harpies:

  - Small Harpies Health: 130 + 70 per minute (patch notes say level but that has to be minute).
  - Elder Harpies Health: 380 + 75 per minute.
- Buff camps:

  - Buff holders health: 440 + 145 per minute.
- Oracles health: 680 + 110 per minute (Oracles have a respawn timer of 3 minutes).

> *All of the above mentioned Jungle (Harpies, buff camps, Oracles) camps in Conquest(and conquest only) have had as of Season 6 a magical.
>   protection increase from 0 to 5*.

- Gold Fury health: 3000 + 275 per minute.
- Pyromancer: 2250 + 250 per minute.
- Fire giant: 7000 + 275 per minute (protections: 110/70, first number is physical and second is magical).
- Enhanced Fire Giant: 8000 + 275 per minute (protections: 125/85, first number is physical and second is magical).

As for the buff timers the buffs last for a total of 2 minutes and in conquest the buff camp respawn timer is also around 2 minutes.

As for the respawn timers of the Gold Fury, Pyromancer and Fire Giant they are all 5 minutes. For further information on their power scaling attack chains and other information [here](https://www.smitegame.com/news/season-6-6-1-update-notes#new-design-features) are the patch notes for Season 6

**Joust:**

- Mana Turtle:

  - Small Mana Turtle health: 320.
  - Mana Turtle Buff holder Health: 1130.
- Power Tiger:

  - Small tiger health: 320.
  - Tiger buff holder: 1130.
- Bull Demon King health: 3844 + 216 per minute.

In Joust however the buff camp respawn timer is 3 minutes or (180 sec).

The Bull Demon King has a respawn timer of 5 minutes.

Keep in mind that as time progresses these values are prone to change.